# Do I need "had" in the following example (past tense)?

Tags: grammar, tense

> For my part I didn't mind her belief. In fact, I was glad she (had) found it
>   back then.

The sentence is in the past tense. And by "back then", the speaker is
referring to many years in the past, then she was a baby.

Do I need to use "had"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> And by "back then", the speaker is referring to many years in the
>   past, then she was a baby.

If you wanted to say that her belief predated your friendship, you would use "had found".  But you would also need an antecedent time reference for "back then" which establishes the time-frame as one that predated your friendship.

Comment: Antecedent time reference? Could you give me an example.

Comment: You need to make clear that "back then" refers to the time when she found belief, not to the time of your gladness, which is how a reader would be likely to understand it. I'd suggest "back when...." instead:  *For my part, I didn't mind her belief. In fact, I was glad she had found it back when she was a child.*

Comment: In antecedent form:   *She found her belief as a child, long before we met. I didn't mind her belief; in fact, I was glad she had found it back then.* But I don't think "back then" is clear enough. As I said, a reader is likely to think you're referring to the time of your friendship, the time of your being glad, not to the time of her childhood.

Comment: TRomano,  What do you say about these sentences: He was glad he had come (0xord). I was sad to hear that your mother had died  (McMillan)..

Comment: @Khan:  I don't see anything wrong with them.  I believe we are in agreement in our replies to the OP.

Answer (score 0):

The OP is correct to use the auxiliary "had" to make the clause in the past perfect. The event (of finding it back) happened earlier than another event (of being glad)in the past.